# Dúvida sobre @media

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

fiz o front-end de um site, no qual seu layout principal estava em 1920px e estou adaptando para outras telas, utilizando:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1920px) {}
```

Vi que no IE8 não está funcionando, existe alguma alternativa para contornar isso?

Comment: Abandonar o IE8 de vez!:)

Comment: Teria que dizer isso à todos os usuários, hehe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O IE8 não suporta media queries, então o que você pode fazer é um fallback para isto utilizando este cara:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

E você pode implementar no seu front de duas maneiras:

```
<!-- Respond.js IE8 support media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="<path>/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Ou utilizando o Modernizr e  verificando o suporte do Browser para media queries

```
Modernizr.load({
   test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
       nope: <path>/respond.min.js
 });
```

Answer (score 8):

Acho que o IE8 não suporta media queries:

http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Então teria de ser uma solução javascript que ouvisse o evento `window.onresize`, e por exemplo, alterasse o atributo `class` do `body` (e.g. algo como `class="width-600"`, ou então `class="width-1000"`), para simular media queries. Assim você poderia colocar no CSS seletores específicos para cada classe atribuída ao `body` pelo script:

```
.width-600 seletor {
    /* estilos para seletor quando a resolução for até 600 */
}

.width-1000 seletor {
    /* estilos para seletor quando a largura for de 600 até 1000 */
}
```

Se estiver usando jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(
    /* função de redimensionamento */
    var w = $(window).width(),
        $body = $("body");
    $body.removeClass("width-600 width-1000");
    $body.addClass(w <= 600 ? "width-600"
        : w <= 1000 ? "width-1000"
        : "width-1000plus");
);
```

A classe `width-1000plus` é para quando a largura for maior que 1000 pixels.

Comment: eu achei um pouco complicado. Existe alguma forma de eu apenas incluir a classe/regra, se tal elemento ultrapassar 1290px?

Comment: `if (w > 1200) $body.addClass("width-1200p");`