# Modificar site de 1290px para 960px

Tags: jquery, css

Terminei o front-end de um site, onde as margens máximas dos elementos vão até 1290px. Agora, tenho o layout para fazê-lo em 960px. Óbvio que irei reutilizar classes.

Eu poderia utilizar o `@media`, mas teria sérios problemas com o **Internet Explorer**.

Exite algum método em JavaScript/Jquery parecido com `@media`?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia condicionalmente definir uma classe para o body de sua página, de acordo com o tamanho da janela.

**EDIT**

Foi mal a demora, é que eu já respondi uma pergunta semelhante aqui no SOPT:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6911/1925

Comment: não entendi. Eu estava pensando em um método, em que ele recebesse o valor total da janela do usuário, se for =< 960px adiciona a regra `siteCont {960px; margin: auto}` se não adiciona a regra `siteCont1290{width: 1290px; margin:auto}`

Comment: Cara, a outra resposta já não era o que você queria? Agora que percebi que foi você mesmo que fez.

Comment: Verdade pessoal, eu tinha feito essa pergunta a algum tempo atrás. Cometi um erro. Por favor, deletem, se possível.